# What is the best way to get members on a cross functional team to respond to deadlines and feedback?

Tags: communication

I lead a cross functional team on an Employee Engagement initiative at my company.  I have several team members who either do not respond to the deadlines I set or come to the meeting unprepared.  The initiative gets treated more like an extra curricular activity rather than part of our jobs.  What can I do to change this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like your team isn't really made up of Engaged Employees yet. Is this a voluntary position, or something pushed on your team members?

Comment: What benefit do those on the team get for their time and what benefit do their managers get for the time lost on their projects?

Comment: It is an extracurricular activity. They still have their real jobs to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this really ís an extracurricular activity, I would expect that any participation is voluntarily. This should also mean that anyone signing up is doing so to achieve something and to make a difference, rather than just hanging out, wasting time. So, you could remind them that to make that difference some goals should be met. Meeting these goals and getting results will give the people their sense of achievement, and will strengthen their engagement.

If this kind of thing is not voluntarily you will get people that are not interested, don't see the point, and would rather go home.

Comment: Thanks for insight, Jeremy. I think you're absolutely spot on with your answer.